# Scrapy: How to crawl the next url in start_urls when a condition is met

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, extract

Is there any way to stop crawling current url and,  jump and crawl the next url in start_urls, when a given condition is met.
Here I test the dates in the page with a pre-defined date.
I want to stop crawling the url when that condition is met.

**Edit**
My code is as follows,

```
class MarketSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = []
    date_limit = datetime.strptime('07/01/2019', '%m/%d,/%Y')
    for url in open("urls.txt"):start_urls.append(url)

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            category = url.split('/')[4]
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta={'category': category})

    def parse(self, response):
        date_limit = self.date_limit
        category = response.request.category

        item_url = response.xpath("//div[@class='white-block-content']")
        for i in item_url:
            url_ = i.xpath("./a/@href").extract_first()
            date = i.xpath("./p[@class='date']/text()").extract_first()
            dt_obj = datetime.strptime(date, '%B %d, %Y')
            if dt_obj >= date_limit:
                yield scrapy.Request(url , callback = self.parse_number, meta={'category': category,'u_date':dt_obj })

        next_page = response.css('a[rel="next"]::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback = self.parse)

    def parse_number(self, response):
        category = response.request.category
        url = response.request.url
        url = url.strip()
        u_date = response.request.u_date
        phone_number = response.xpath("//div[@id='contact-top']//li/@data-value").extract()
        for i in phone_number:
            yield {
                'category': category, 
                'u_date': u_date,
                'url': url, 
                'phone_number': i}
```

Comment: please show your code how are you doing?

Comment: code is added. please check

Answer (score 1):

Simply calling return after yield worked for me:

```
yield {
   'lorem': 'ipsum'
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `parse_number` function, check the condition for matching the date. If the condition matches yield the data and stop crawling from the specific domain. else continue the rest crawling.

Comment: can you please elaborate, how to stop crawling when the condition is matched.

Comment: create a list and add those URLs whose condition matches and when a new iteration occurs check with the list for avoiding those URLs. Eg: `If URL not in self.processed_urls:`

Comment: so how to end the crawling for each url? closespider won't work.